# How to transfer apache ssl certificate from cent os to debian

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I have a VPS running cent os 7 and I need to transfer the SSL certificate from it to a dedicated running debian .SSL was made in gandi.net.

The problem I have in debian I must configure apache 2 using the :

```
    SSLCertificateFile
```

and

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile
```

but in my VPS cent os http configuration I can not find this directives , I only found this :

```
cat  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog     builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex                default
SSLRandomSeed           startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed           connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice         builtin
```

And I do not know where are the files I have to put for SSLCertificateFile   and SSLCertificateKeyFile  in the devian dedicated.

Comment: Look through the apache config files on the debian server and find where the cert and key are currently stored.

Comment: The `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` is almost certainly the wrong file to be looking at to find the current configuration, that section is all about web server defaults.  Your SSL certs configuration will almost certainly be associated with a specific virtual host.  If I were you I would try doing something like `grep -iR SSLCertificate /etc/httpd` and see what shows up.